# Prototype 2: Lairs location map

Tags: prototype-2

Is there a location map for the lairs in Prototype 2?

I have been trying to find these all morning, but I couldn't find any.

Is there a easier way to find them without a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a map by IGN: http://www.ign.com/wikis/prototype-2/Lairs

Here is a link to the co-ordinates of the lairs: http://thecontrolleronline.com/2012/05/prototype-2-infected-lair-locations-guide/

Here is another link with co-ordinates: http://segmentnext.com/2012/04/24/prototype-2-lairs-locations-guide-how-to-destroy/

Answer (score 2):

All lairs and other collectibles are beeing "pinged" when you are on the ingame map on the curent island you are located on.
You will just need to wait a bit. When you see a "ping" make a waypoint to it and get there.
As soon as the collectible is collected or the lair cleared, it will no longer be pinged on the map.

Also have a [link](http://www.ign.com/wikis/prototype-2/Lairs), but be advised thet link might get taken down and the ingame mechanics provide you with a way to locate the lairs and collectibles.

You further need to have a certain degree of story progression to unlock the ability to enter the lairs. The first lair will be entered in a story mission.